# Python strftime days without ZERO

Tags: python, string, date

Why doesn't the codes from this page work?: http://strftime.org/.
I want to output date and months without leading zeroes, like **'m/d/yyyy'**

e.g.:
**'4/5/1992' YES**

'04/05/1992' NO

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
yest = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(21), '%-m-%-d-%Y')
print(yest)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-7c70a0a7eee5> in <module>
      1 from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
----> 2 yest = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(21), '%-m-%-d-%Y')
      3 print(yest)

ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `%-m` option does state that the format is platform specific, so mileage may vary.

You can simply use f-strings in Python 3.

```
yest = datetime.now() - timedelta(21)
yest = f'{yest.month}/{yest.day}/{yest.year}'
>>> yest
'10/9/2019'
```

In the case of your dataframe explained in the comments:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'fecha_vencimiento': [
        '12/25/2009', '01/05/2010', '04/13/2011', '']})

df['fecha_vencimiento'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['fecha_vencimiento'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce').apply(
        lambda x: f'{x.month}/{x.day}/{x.year}' 
        if pd.notnull(x) else '')
```

Comment: thanks!! for example i have this column of dates, but give me error: f'{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].month}/{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].day}/{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].year}

Comment: Try using the `dt` accessor function, `f'{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].dt.month}/{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].dt.day}/{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].dt.year}'`

Comment: give me SyntaxError: invalid syntax :(

Comment: df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'] = f'{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].dt.month}/{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].dt.day}/{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].dt.year}'

Comment: What is the output of `type(df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'])`? That is, what do the date values currently look like? Strings, datetime values, timestamps, etc.

Comment: 'for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'] = pd.to_datetime(df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'])
df['fecha_vencimiento'] = df['fecha_vencimiento'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')if not pd.isnull(x) else '')
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    if df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'] != "":
        df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'] = f'{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].dt.month}/{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].dt.day}/{df.at[idx,'fecha_vencimiento'].dt.year}'

Comment: sorry, i cant put this in code mode, the type is STR

Comment: some columns have empty rows date

Answer (score 2):

The %-d would give you the day without the leading 0 and %-m the month, but this format only works on Unix (Linux, OS X), not Windows (including Cygwin). On Windows, you would use #, e.g. %#d, %#m.